# Golang error group over function with custom signature

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a function, say, `func foo(x) error { if x == y ... return err}` that I would like to execute in several go routines and aggregate the errors (preferably using an error group as with the common example below), but not sure if that's possible?

```
   import "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"

   var g errgroup.Group

   g.Go(func() error {
      resp, err := http.Get(url)
      if err == nil {
         resp.Body.Close()
      }
      return err
   })
```

Comment: Have you tried https://play.golang.org/p/ldJzkiP-Cjp? If that's not an option explain why.

Comment: "not sure if that's possible" - did you try? What problem did you encounter? If you know what you want to do and how, the easiest way to find out if it works is to **try it**. Then if you run into a problem you can't solve, post a question.

Comment: I see my question has been misunderstood -  I should've explained that I obviously had been trying to make it work for a long time, but the syntax seemed impossible because I was confusing the outer function for mine. Silly in hindsight. I might need some sleep X_x Thanks to @mkopriva. Working now. I'm still glad I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as proposed by @mkopriva.

```
var g errgroup.Group
var x interface{}

g.Go(func() error {
   return foo(x)
})
```

Simples.

Comment: Horrible idea if you are passing parameters in a loop https://play.golang.org/p/Jvo_0LI8AxO

Comment: This answer is wrong; the @nguyenhoai890 's answer is correct

Answer (score 8):

As @Homulvas pointed out in the comment, it's a horrible idea if you are passing parameters in the loop to the go routine which makes an enclosure func. Here is the link to reproduce the mentioned problem (from Homulvas): https://play.golang.org/p/Jvo_0LI8AxO

It seems that you want to scan the list of urls by go routines, So FYI,  to fix it, you can declare a func in the loop to init go routine for error as example as below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

func scan(x string) error {
    // if x == y ... return err
    fmt.Println(x)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var g errgroup.Group
    urls := []string{"a.com", "b.com", "c.com", "d.com"}
    for _, url := range urls {
        func(scanningUrl string) {
            g.Go(func() error {
                return scan(scanningUrl)
            })
        }(url)
    }

    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        //
    }
}
```

link: https://play.golang.org/p/XtfD1AFsdYt

Comment: This should be chosen as the correct answer, actually